# Python wont run inside CMD, PS, or VS Code

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, command-prompt

I am a learner, so please forgive me if this is common knowledge

I fixed my PATH files for python, I made the only PATH and sole instance of Python C:\Python
This fixed the issue where VS code could not find a python interpreter.

Now that I have done this, when when i try to run a python command, this happens:

`PS C:\Users\sajja\Documents\git\cs50w_repo\cs50w_lecturepractice\lecture2-python> python name.py`
but it never prompts me for the input, which is the whole point of this file.

when i check the python install, vscode does recognize it, just wont run it

> PS C:\Users\sajja\Documents\git\cs50w_repo\cs50w_lecturepractice\lecture2-python> python
> Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

If i switch to the output tab and do it from there instead, it runs the code without error, but never prompts me for the input, and therefore never prints the output

> [Running] python -u "c:\Users\sajja\Documents\git\cs50w_repo\cs50w_lecturepractice\lecture2-python\name.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.057 seconds

I was expecting for this code:

```
name = input("Name: ")
print(name)
```

to prompt me to enter an input, and then print said input in the output or terminal

Comment: I am assuming the terminal built into VS Code is the integrated one, if that is correct then that is the one that I was using. My solution that I posted below is odd, but I did restart vs code and try it again, and it did work again. And yes I did have the python extension for VS code installed prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: I'm assuming that your problems are limited to running in Visual Studio Code. Assuming the `python` executable is discoverable via `$env:PATH`, you should *not* experience problems when running your script in regular console windows or Windows Terminal.</sup>

- In order **to run *interactive* console (terminal-based) code in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), it must run in the *integrated terminal***, which is the **`TERMINAL` tab in the panel** (you can toggle the latter's visibility with <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>):

  - [image: screenshot with integrated terminal]
- By contrast, **the `OUTPUT` tab is *not* designed for or capable of running interactive console applications**.

  - It is used by extensions such as [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), which, via its `Run Code` command runs code *invisibly* and captures its *output* only, which is printed to the `OUTPUT` tab - any interactive prompts will actually cause the hidden process to effectively *hang*, because no interactive input can be provided. (There is an opt-in configuration setting that allows you to run in the terminal instead, but it only works for entire, already-saved files).
  - **It is best to install a *language-specific debugger***, which not only (always and by default) properly executes code in the *terminal*, but also supports *debugging*.
- Specifically, for Python files:

  - **Install the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)**.

    - VSCode offers to do that for you the first time you open a Python script for editing.
  - The **run your code as follows**:

    - <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the current script in the debugger (supporting breakpoints, stepping through the code, ...)
    - <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> to run your script normally.
    - There's also <kbd>Shift-Enter</kbd> for executing the *currently selected lines* in an interactive `python` session, but note that this doesn't work for *interactive* code snippets, because the lines are pasted *one by one*, so that the code line after the `input()` call is accidentally pasted as the response to the input prompt.
    - Of course, you can also invoke run and debug functionality *via the GUI*, such as via the `Run and Debug` view (selectable via the [image: Run and Debug icon] icon in the leftmost side bar), the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd>) or via the playback icon to the right of the editor pane:

      - [image: screenshot with playback icon]

Comment: thanks a lot, I keep running into minor issues which probably are obvious, I also figured this out, at first terminal wouldnt work either, but by choosing "Run and Debug" versus just Run, it started doing what i wanted it to! Idk what that changd, but now it shows terminal by default, instead of just the output panel!

Comment: Mysterious, @SajjadAhmed, but I'm glad it works now and that the answer helped.

Comment: A new oddity has presented itself, 
when I run some basic code, in the Run drop down menu the options are
-Run Code
-Run Python
-Debug Python File
when I run code, for some reason it only runs what has been debugged, not any changes afterwards.
When i run python file, i get an error about syntax (???)
And when I Run Python file and Debug, it works exactly like its supposed to

Comment: @SajjadAhmed, I only see `Run Python File` and `Debug Python File`, so it sounds like you have an additional extension installed; the aforementioned `Code Runner` extension would add a `Run Code` command, which you should avoid. Not sure about syntax errors and running old code - I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar questions, but I could'nt find an exact one.
Here is the solution I found:

Instead of running the file in VSCode, I selected Run and Debug, which opened a different terminal (maybe?), this terminal accepts input, and therefore printed the correct output.

Here it is:

> PS C:\Users\sajja\Documents\git\cs50w_repo\cs50w_lecturepractice> & C:/Python/python.exe c:/Users/sajja/Documents/git/cs50w_repo/cs50w_lecturepractice/lecture2-python/name.py
> Name: sajjad
> sajjad

The output window still does not do what it is supposed to, but the Terminal window is behaving the way it should

Comment: `Run and Debug` indeed runs the active script in _the_ terminal built into Visual Studio Code, called the _integrated terminal_ (tab `TERMINAL`), where - as in any terminal - interactive functionality _is_ supported. By contrast, the `OUTPUT` tab is _not_ designed to function as a terminal, and has no interactive support.